# Bootstrap 3 Horizontal Center Button Group In A Row

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to horizontally center two radio buttons (in a group) on my page.  This is what I have so far.  It is not exactly center.  It is a bit to the left.  Pull right makes it go too far to the right.  I added center-block and text-center but they did not help at all.

Can anyone help?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="btn-group center-block text-center" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default center-block"><input type="radio">All</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default active center-block"><input type="radio">Filtered</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have `text-center` in the parent div, not the div being centered.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default center-block"><input type="radio">All</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default active center-block"><input type="radio">Filtered</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should use `col-sm-offset-5` instead of `<div class="col-sm-5">&nbsp;</div>`.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/8kfO7P6EJ4)

Comment: Thanks @Dan, that really helps me understand the Bootstrap grid system.  The offsets make a bit more sense to me now.  There is lots of documentation available on their website but a simple example like this helps one understand simple concepts much better!